# heroku django not collecting my static files

Tags: django, heroku, django-models, django-forms, heroku-postgres

My question is :
When i run collectstatic command  staticfiles on heroku server my app didn't copied  my staticfiles ?

my configuration :

```
**BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))**
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_in_env","static_root")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static_in_pro","our_static"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Django takes the static files from `STATICFILES_DIRS` and `static` folders inside installed apps into `STATIC_ROOT`.

You should check for sure that you have your static files inside your folder:  `BASE_DIR/static_in_pro/our_static`.

The simplest way is to create a `static` folder inside your app and than put your static files inside it . In this case, you can ignore `STATICFILES_DIRS`.